# Host refused connection when using ftp

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, sftp, port-forwarding

I need to connect to my server using FTP, but connection refuses. I have been using SFTP that is working just fine (both locally and externally). Using linux debian. I am able to login with ftp locally, but need to gain external access.

I have opened all required ports (I think so at least, ports 20-23), tried different softwares and reinstalling em, but nothing seems to be working. Tried also few different configurations and disabling `ssh`. I don't know if I have configured something to block external access or what it is - I am rather new to Linux environment. The port itself should be open (not blocked by isp) and ipv6 seemed to be listening to it.

I have gone through hundreds of forum posts and spent ages googling, but cant really come up with anything. Might be that I don't even properly know what to look for. [Here](https://pastebin.com/tqiqPNX4) is copy of my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES
```

Comment: SSH (`ssh` and `scp` and `sftp`) does not have anything to do with `ftp`. You say you're able to connect to your server from the server itself? How are you connecting then? Is the `ftp` service listening on an external port, or only on a port on `localhost`? Does "externally" mean from another machine on the same subnet, or on a truly external machine outside the local network?

Comment: By locally I mean inside the same network using local 192.168.... ip address from another computer. And I need to gain access from external mahcine outside the local network. Trying to connect using winscp. Tried to find listened ports using 'lsof -i -P' and ' netstat -pln' commands, but couldnt find it there.

Comment: With WinSCP, are you sure you're using the FTP protocol and not SCP or SFTP?

Comment: Yes I am sure its FTP, but now I am unable to even connect to port 21 locally - port 22 with SFTP still working locally and externally

Answer (score 1):

FTP protocol requires second inbound connection from FTP server to FTP client to transfer data by default. Frequently users does not have public IPv4 address so can not receive inbound connections from anywhere or client's host can not accept inbound connection for security purposes. For same cases FTP protocol can use passive mode also. This passive mode uses second outbound connection from FTP client to FTP server.

Step 1. Please try to enable **passive mode** at your FTP client to use data outbound connection from FTP client to FTP server.

All web browser's use passive mode always.

Many FTP clients do not use passive mode by default so it need to enable the mode.

For example, classic FTP client `ftp` has `-p` option to enable passive mode.

Step 2. Please enable passive mode at your server. You need to add passive mode options at your config of vsftpd server:

```
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=11000
pasv_promiscuous=NO
pasv_address=111.122.133.144
```

Please change value of `pasv_address`. I have used these options for same purposes.

You can change interval of TCP ports if required. FTP server and FTP client will negotiate that at handshake.

Step 3. Please allow incoming connections for TCP ports 10000-11000 at FTP server's firewall.

NB. The FTP protocol is not secure to use over public networks. User's password transfers as plain text and this data can be captured. FTP protocol still applicable to public access to files in read only mode. To secure FTP protocol you need use VPN.

Comment: Hey! I am trying to login using winscp that apparently defaults to passive mode. I added the config you gave to vsftpd.conf file and edited the pasv_address to local address of the server (192.168.1.3). Also forwarded all ports TCP and UDP 10000-11000, but still cant get through externally. It is very possible that I have just messed up something very simple - Like I said I am not an expert when it comes to this enviroment. Thanks for the help though!